# My edit where I made images inline for user with low reputation has votes to reject

Tags: discussion, edits

I edited the following question to convert image links to inline images:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36979678/architecture-of-desktop-application-single-user-with-the-mvvm-pattern-and-entit

Two users have approved it while two users have cast reject votes.  The rejecting users have both provided the following reason:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
>   easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either
>   completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

The edit is still pending at this time.  I have provided many such edits before where I only do inline image conversions and they have all been approved.

My question: If the edit in question is rejected, what recourse do I have? How can I raise an issue about it?

Comment: There are bad reviewers out there. Move on.

Comment: Of course, the question is off-topic as opinion based but that's not relevant to the issue.

Comment: @Paulie_D It can be relevant. If a question is off-topic and not fit for another site, it should be closed. (Speaking in the general case, not judging this particular case). If a post can't be salvaged, editing is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: True but in this case, that's not the reason given...although that might be an auto-comment.

Comment: That said, it could be argued that the images don't add anything...I'd tend to disagree but the size is annoying. Obviously, opinions are 50/50 on this one....and I see someone has re-edited them out.

Comment: @Paulie_D I agree, it's not the easiest one to judge. I have a hunch that question can be salvaged.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thank you for your insight, much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That question is off-topic (opinion based / tool recommendation). Don't waste time (yours and reviewers') editing off-topic questions.

Another reason for rejecting is that the images add nothing that isn't already conveyed in the text. This site very strongly dislikes images that aren't *absolutely* necessary.

Comment: Didn't know that images were disliked.  When someone posts screenshots of error messages, I always leave a comment telling them to post text as text.  I am accepting your answer and will "move on" as others have said! :)

Answer (score 2):

You've already found the only recourse: raise the issue on Meta.

It will not turn back the fact that the edit was rejected. Someone might re-do the edit, helping the OP. And if the reject gave you an edit suspension, a moderator *might* turn the suspension back - if it really was a good edit.

By the way, a single rejected edit won't give you a suspension. It takes a pattern of bad edits to get one.

That said, the purpose of every edit should be to improve the post. One could argue that this particular post is primarily opinion-based and should be closed, not edited. Personally, I'm withholding judgment on this particular post.
But as a general rule, only edit things if they are worth editing. There's no point in editing things that should be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your insight.